# Segue data from a collectioview to two container at the same time in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, containers, segue

I have a collectionview and when passing data to another view I can with out problems but when I try to pass to two containers in the same viewcontroller  I get unexpectedly found nil unwrapping an Optional value.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26491028/what-to-do.jpg

So I want to show in one container the image from selected item in the collection
and in the other container I want to set label.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegueVC" {

        if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MainController {
            .......
        }
    }
}
```

I have create a controller for each container

```
class Container1 : MainController{

override func viewDidload(){
    print(detaildata) =====> gives the error
}
```

........

```
class Container2 : MainController{
```

if I set the data on maincontroller all is working:

```
class MainController: UIViewController {

var detaildata : data!

override func viewDidload(){
    print(detaildata)
}
```

But if I try to get values passed from segue in Container 1 or 2 I get the error.

Can someone give a clue how to segue data from collection to each containers embed on maincontainer.

thanks in advice

Comment: tried printing detaildata in viewWillAppea() ?

Comment: How are you trying to pass data to `container1` and `container2` objects?  (Please capitalize the first letter of a class name; it reduces confusion.)

Comment: I've tried with differents ways, doing a performSegueWithIdentifier() at MainController class, also I tried to do it from collection view, also I've tried to remove embed segue and do one directly from collection view to Container 1 view... ( sorry about capitalizing..fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Well I will give you an example (with the structure that you have) of how you can accomplish this:

- Basically go directly to the method setupControllers in MainViewController, what I do there, I setup every controller that I want to put (ex. ImageViewController (Image), DataViewController (Label), although it's going to depends on your needs), and add these controllers as Child of your MainViewController.

https://github.com/Abreu0101/PassingDataSample

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna study I have seen that you have removed the automatic embed segue.